# Magento 2.2.5 Issue when checking value 'Yes' for yes/no attribute

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute

The following piece of code:

```
$yesNo = $product->getData('upcoming');
if($yesNo = "Yes") {
    $labels['upcoming'] = 'Upcoming';
}
```

Is supposed to add a label on products for which the yes/no attribute has been set on 'Yes', but now all products get the label (even those for which the value of the attribute is 'No')

How to correct for this?

Comment: You need to use `==` instead of `=` in your `if` condition. Also try using value `1` or `0` to check `Yes` and `No` respectively.

Comment: == "Yes", == 'Yes', == "yes", =='yes', == '1' and == "1" do not work

Comment: Have you checked the value for your variable `$yesNo` by using `var_dump($yesNo)`? Make sure you are getting the value in your variable before using it in your condition.

Comment: May be re-indexing and clearing your cache could help.

Comment: have you tried `echo $product->getUpcoming();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code to get value for your attribute

```
$yesNo = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('upcoming')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Then you can check the value by using `var_dump($yesNo)` for your product attribute.

Comment: var_dump returns NO for all products, irrespective of the value of the yes/no attribute: object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#3246 (2) { ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> string(2) "No" ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: If you are using this on product list page, just try setting the value for the first product in the list to 'Yes'. It may happen that the product object you are using is being cached and gets value from the same object every time.

Comment: I checked already, but still var_dump returns NO for all products (even for those for which the attribute is Yes)  the attribute code is ok; anything else to bear in mind?

Comment: I cant think of anything else which can cause this issue except if the scope of your attribute. If it is `store_view`, then you may require to check the attribute value for the particular store in admin panel.

Comment: Jaimin, the issue was related to the configuration of the attribute :) i only have an extra question: that check works for simple products, but what about configurable ones? Should all childs and the parent have the value ‘Yes’ so that a similar check can also work for configurable products?

Comment: Glad to know its resolved. For configurable products, you can directly assign the value to main configurable product. If you want it to be based on values of all associated products, then it will require to get all children of the config product and then match with each product's value for the attribute.

Comment: Jaimin, how did you fix it? it is showing No for simple product as well